# References for path-dependent GBMs or continuous time analog of discrete time filters

Tags: reference-request, sde, geometric-brownian

Consider a path-dependent GBM model for a stock price:
$$dS_t = \mu(t, S_.)S_tdt + \sigma(t, S_.) S_t dB_t,$$
where $\mu, \sigma : [0,\infty)\times C_{[0,\infty)}\to \mathbb{R}$ are previsible path-functionals.

Does anyone know of any references of papers on this generalization and if there are any standard choices for $\mu$, $\sigma$ that are well studied?

Some examples:
We might consider a drift in two forms:
$$\mu(t, S_.) = \int_0^t f(S_u) du$$
or say
$$\mu(t,S_.) = g(m_t, M_t),$$
where $m_t = \min_{0\leq u \leq t} S_u$ and $M_t = \max_{0\leq u \leq t} S_u$ and $f$ and $g$ are nice enough functions. These incorporate path-dependency in a sort of arbitrary way, but what might be some judicious choices? For example, $f(S_u)=e^{\lambda S_u}$ would "weight" recent prices heavier than past prices. Another way to phrase this might be: is there a survey of continuous time analogs of discrete time filters, like moving averages, EWMAs, etc?

Edit:

I am not looking for online resources, I know of those and am searching among those, I was wondering if anybody already knew of *specific papers* about these topics. Like if you ask for functional Ito calculus, the classic to start with might be Bruno Dupire's paper on functional Ito calculus and he lists a variety of discrete time path-dependent functionals but does not go into much details about treating them in continuous time.